# Php Excel, bar and line graph possibility?

Tags: phpexcel

Is it possible to create a line and bar graph using PHPExcel? Like this one below.

[image]

If not is it possible to make a graph background transparent so I can merge two graphs together?

Comment: yes its possible, how is this a php or a stack overflow question?

Comment: This is definitely for superuser.com (flagged to move): this is easily achievable via adding second plot with independent axis and type.

Comment: not sure where this is in the world, but its cold and wet, glad i don't live there

Comment: I put it in stackoverflow because I wanted to know if its possible using PHP Excel, a PHP libary that creates Excel documents, graphs etc.

Comment: You probably should've just tagged it PhpExcel then and not the other things.  Someone who's just an Excel reader, or PHP reader, won't know this after all.  Not sure I think it should be moved though; this is a programming question, isn't it?

Comment: well now you tell us, not psychic- and yes you can do it with PHPExcel.

Comment: Is there an example or area in the documentation that can help me with this? An example of setting graph background to transparent would be very good as well, thanks

Comment: You can't get a second axis, but (as Peter L has said) you can add a second plot with a different type

Comment: is there any documentation to make a start on what you are talking about @MarkBaker

Comment: Nope, but I'm putting together an example now

Comment: One thing that would be very helpful is if PHPExcel can set a No FIll to the chart and plot area and then i can overlay two graphs, giving the effect they are one graph. Been searching through the code and it seems that fills are only supported for cells?

Answer (score 11):

I had to make a minor tweak to the PHPExcel code to get it working correctly, just pushed it to github; together with 33chartcreate-composite-chart.php in /Examples.

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array('',       'Rainfall (mm)',    'Temperature (°F)', 'Humidity (%)'),
        array('Jan',        78,                 52,                 61),
        array('Feb',        64,                 54,                 62),
        array('Mar',        62,                 57,                 63),
        array('Apr',        21,                 62,                 59),
        array('May',        11,                 75,                 60),
        array('Jun',        1,                  75,                 57),
        array('Jul',        1,                  79,                 56),
        array('Aug',        1,                  79,                 59),
        array('Sep',        10,                 75,                 60),
        array('Oct',        40,                 68,                 63),
        array('Nov',        69,                 62,                 64),
        array('Dec',        89,                 57,                 66),
    )
);


//  Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataseriesLabels1 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1', NULL, 1),   //  Temperature
);
$dataseriesLabels2 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1', NULL, 1),   //  Rainfall
);
$dataseriesLabels3 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$1', NULL, 1),   //  Humidity
);

//  Set the X-Axis Labels
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$xAxisTickValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$13', NULL, 12),    //  Jan to Dec
);


//  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataSeriesValues1 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$13', NULL, 12),
);

//  Build the dataseries
$series1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues1)-1),          // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels1,                             // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues1                              // plotValues
);
//  Set additional dataseries parameters
//      Make it a vertical column rather than a horizontal bar graph
$series1->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);


//  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataSeriesValues2 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$13', NULL, 12),
);

//  Build the dataseries
$series2 = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,      // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,   // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues2)-1),          // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels2,                             // plotLabel
    NULL,                                           // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues2                              // plotValues
);


//  Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
//      Datatype
//      Cell reference for data
//      Format Code
//      Number of datapoints in series
//      Data values
//      Data Marker
$dataSeriesValues3 = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$13', NULL, 12),
);

//  Build the dataseries
$series3 = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_AREACHART,      // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,   // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues2)-1),          // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels3,                             // plotLabel
    NULL,                                           // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues3                              // plotValues
);


//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series1, $series2, $series3));
//  Set the chart legend
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);

$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Average Weather Chart for Crete');


//  Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',       // name
    $title,         // title
    $legend,        // legend
    $plotarea,      // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,           // xAxisLabel
    NULL            // yAxisLabel
);

//  Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('F2');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('O16');

//  Add the chart to the worksheet
$objWorksheet->addChart($chart);
```

Comment: I will look at this and see if I can implement this as a solution, will get back to you.

Comment: Best charting example I have seen so far. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mark, have you successfully add secondary axis for the temperature ? thank you